# Clear or delete variable before declaring it again with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am VERY NEW to javascript and am messing around with some math. I currently have:

```
<input disabled="disabled" type="text" id="backer-prediction-answer" width="100" value="" />

<FORM> 
    <INPUT type="button" value="Apply" name="button1" onclick="apply()">
</FORM>

<script>
var backerPrediction1 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-1").value;
var backerPrediction2 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-2").value;
var backerPrediction3 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-3").value;
var backerPrediction4 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-4").value;

function apply(){
    var backers = parseInt(backerPrediction1,10) + parseInt(backerPrediction2,10);
    document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = (backers);
}
</script>
```

I would like to be able to hit apply and have it recalculate. Do I need to delete the variable before declaring it again? If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the variables backerPredictionX inside the function, so that they are evaluated everytime you apply()

```
<script>

function apply(){
    var backerPrediction1 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-1").value;
    var backerPrediction2 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-2").value;

    var backers = parseInt(backerPrediction1,10) + parseInt(backerPrediction2,10);
    document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = (backers);
}
</script>
```

---

With jquery (code not validated):

```
function apply(){
    var backerPrediction1 = $("#backer-prediction-1").val();
    var backerPrediction2 = $("#backer-prediction-2").val();

    var backers = parseInt(backerPrediction1,10) + parseInt(backerPrediction2,10);
    $("#backer-prediction-answer").val(backers);
}
```

Comment: RAHH!! Awesome!! Thanks!! So new to this, very much appreciated!! So much fun! (it says I have to wait 5 minutes to accept this!)

Comment: glad it helped. If you are creating anything non trivial, consider using jquery.

Comment: Can you give me an example? please :)

Comment: Thanks!!! Think you could help here too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534341/anyway-to-simplify-this-code