# Any way to simplify this code?

Tags: javascript

New to javascript! This works, but I have a lot more to do, and it would be great if there was a cleaner way to do this.. open to using jquery if neccesary :)

(stack wants me to write more before I submit, though I'm not sure what else to say)

```
<script>

function apply(){
    var backerPrediction1 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-1").value;
    var backerPrediction2 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-2").value;
    var backerPrediction3 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-3").value;
    var backerPrediction4 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-4").value;
    var backerPrediction5 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-5").value;
    var backerPrediction6 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-6").value;
    var backerPrediction7 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-7").value;
    var backerPrediction8 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-8").value;
    var backerPrediction9 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-9").value;
    var backerPrediction10 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-10").value;
    var backerPrediction11 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-11").value;
    var backerPrediction12= document.getElementById("backer-prediction-12").value;
    var backerPrediction13 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-13").value;
    var backerPrediction14 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-14").value;
    var backerPrediction15 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-15").value;
    var backerPrediction16 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-16").value;
    var backerPrediction17 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-17").value;
    var backerPrediction18 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-18").value;
    var backerPrediction19 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-19").value;
    var backers = parseInt(backerPrediction1,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction2,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction3,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction4,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction5,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction6,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction7,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction8,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction9,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction10,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction11,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction12,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction13,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction14,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction15,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction16,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction17,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction18,10) +
              parseInt(backerPrediction19,10)
;
document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = (backers);
}
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd do it something like this:

```
function apply() {
    var backers = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < 20; ++i) {
        backers +=
            parseInt(document.getElementById("backer-prediction-" + i).value);
    }
    document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = backers;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could you show me what this would replace? (new) THANKS!!

Comment: @Reuben - It would replace the entire body of your `apply()` function. I updated the code to clarify this.

Comment: @TedHopp: I changed `backers` to be `0`, not `''`.  If it was a blank string, the values would be concated to the string and not added together.

Comment: @Reuben -- Oops. Mismatched parens. Now that's fixed. It's too late at night for me to be writing code. :(

Comment: waiting the 4 minutes stack requires to hit the check

Comment: Ok and this one gets a little more complicated, and will hopefully show me enough to start writing these myself! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534555/how-to-simplify-this-javascript

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to go about this would be to give each of the `backer-prediction-#` elements a class and grab all of them:

```
var backerEls = document.querySelectorAll('.backer-prediction');
//Get a list of all the elements with the class 'backer-prediction'
var backers = 0;
//Total
for (var i = 0; i < backerEls.length; i++) {
    //Loop over the elements
    backers += parseInt(backerEls[i].value, 10);
    //Parse their values and add them to the total
}

console.log(backers);​
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2VHLn/2/))

This lets you have as many elements as you want without having to update your JS at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = 0;
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
 answer += parseInt(document.getElementById("backer-prediction-" + i).value), 10);
}

document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = answer;
```

Comment: You probably want `< 20`, not `<= 20`. :-P

Comment: So what is the difference between your answer and Ted Hopp's other than i++.

Comment: His was incorrect at the time I wrote, he edited and fixed after (or while) I posted. Originally his concated a string rather than addition. His is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to get the backers total.

```
function apply(){
    var answer = getBackers();
    document.getElementById("backer-prediction-answer").value = answer;
}

function getBackers()
{
    var baseName = "backer-prediction-";
    var elementId = "";
    var backers = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < 20; i++)
    {
        elementId = baseName + i;
        backers = backers + getElementValue(elementId);
    }

    return backers;
}

function getElementValue(elementId)
{
    var value = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-1").value;
    return parseInt(value, 10);
}
```