# How to simplify this javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to simplify this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534341/any-way-to-simplify-this-code)

What is the best way to simplify this for going from 1-19?

```
var backer1 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-1").value;
var incentive1 = document.getElementById("incentive-cost-1").value;
var totalIncentive1 = parseInt(backer1,10) * parseInt(incentive1,10);

document.getElementById("incentive-total-1").value = totalIncentive1;

var backer2 = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-2").value;
var incentive2 = document.getElementById("incentive-cost-2").value;
var totalIncentive2 = parseInt(backer2,10) * parseInt(incentive2,10);

document.getElementById("incentive-total-2").value = totalIncentive2;
```

Last one I posted they gave me a "for" loop.

Still learning this stuff.. Very New, THANKS!!!

Comment: And the "for" loop did not work in this case, as well?

Comment: the for loop was for other code, and I am not sure how to apply it to this :/

Comment: I'm hoping after I see how it applies to this, I can start writing it myself :)

Comment: You should be able to apply the same answer given to you in the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534341/any-way-to-simplify-this-code), so I'm voting to close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how, I was hoping to see how it applied to this so I can write my own for the rest I'm trying to do..

Comment: You should at least *try* and show what you can come up with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534341/any-way-to-simplify-this-code), use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for(var i = 1; i < 20; i++){
    var backer = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-"+i).value;
    var incentive = document.getElementById("incentive-cost-"+i).value;
    var totalIncentive = parseInt(backer,10) * parseInt(incentive,10);

    document.getElementById("incentive-total-"+i).value = totalIncentive;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! you removed the 1's from the variables backer and totalIncentive, should it be removed from inventive too?

Comment: @Reuben: It doesn't really matter, but to be consistent, yes.  It's 1am, so I just kinda missed it.

Comment: I removed the numbers as well, in my answer, because they are really not important to store as an array. Will would only need to store that as an array if you needed to get the exact values for each one of the elements.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.. I think I need the variables to have those following numbers to increase as well.. and the totalIncentive

Comment: @Reuben: The variables can be called whatever you want, it doesn't matter.  It might not have worked because of a typo (I had `backer1` instead of `backer`) :-P  Try it now.

Answer (score 3):

Use Array in javascript

```
var backer=[],
    incentive=[],
    totalincentive=[];
for(var i=1;i<20;i++){
    backer[i] = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-"+i).value;
    incentive[i] = document.getElementById("incentive-cost-"+i).value;
    totalIncentive[i] = parseInt(backer[i],10) * parseInt(incentive[1],10);

    document.getElementById("incentive-total-"+i).value = totalIncentive[i];
}
```

So you can use them after ending for loop , like

```
backer[1]....,backer[19]
incentive[1]....,incentive[19]
totalincentive[1]....,totalincentive[19]
```

Comment: I'm getting an error on the var backer... line in dreamweaver :/

Answer (score 3):

```
for (var i=1; i<=19; i++) {
    var backer = document.getElementById("backer-prediction-" + i).value;
    var incentive = document.getElementById("incentive-cost-" + i).value;
    var totalIncentive = parseInt(backer,10) * parseInt(incentive,10);
    document.getElementById("incentive-total-" + i).value = totalIncentive;
}
```

This untested code should be enough, unless you need access to the `backer` and `incentive` values for each one of the cases after the loop is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of *backer* and *incentive* is a number, I'd be tempted to do:

```
var get = document.getElementById;
var backer, incentive, totalIncentive = 0;

for(var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
  totalIncentive += get("backer-prediction-" + i).value * get("incentive-cost-" + i).value;
}
```

as the multiplication will implicitly convert numeric strings to numbers. But you really should validate that the content of those elements is a valid number before doing anything, even if using *parseInt*.